# Why does pandas store a boolean index with an object dtype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let me define a simple dataframe:

```
In  [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [True, False], 'b': [1, 2]})
```

The data type of the `'a'` column is stored as `bool`:

```
In  [2]: df['a'].dtype
Out [2]: dtype('bool')
```

If I then set `'a'` as the index column of the dataframe:

```
In  [3]: df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
```

The dtype of the index column is now `object`:

```
In  [4]: df.index
Out [4]: Index([True, False], dtype='object', name='a')
```

If I use the integer column `'b'` as the index, the dtype of the index is as expected:

```
In  [5]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)
         df.set_index('b', inplace=True)
         df.index
Out [5]: Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='b')
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: object include bool ,string , date...etc

Answer (score 0):

In what case would you want to make a boolean value an index? An index is supposed to be a unique identifier for the row, I would assume Pandas does this so that you do not have a duplicate index.

Comment: I'm doing a `value_counts()` on all categorical columns in a dataframe, which returns count values with the original categories as the index. I then want to be able to re-create a similar dataframe from these value counts (i'm turning them into probabilities), but the dtypes in the new dataframe are out of whack for boolean columns.

Comment: Maybe you could try changing the dtype once you have made the dataframe? You could use the astype() function to set it to whatever type you need it. As to WHY this happens? Not sure.

Comment: Aye, I'm currently having to pass in the desired dtypes explicitly rather than being able to rely on the dtype of the index value, hence this question.